# Removing specific string from lines in file using sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have a file like so:

```
asdsdf
www.sdf
wwwasdsdsds
gegergreg
```

I want the following output:

```
asdsdf
sdf
wwwasdsdsds
gegergreg
```

What I tried is:

```
sed '^www.'/d myfile.txt
```

But this is not what I want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
 sed 's/^www\.//' FileName
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sed -i.bak s/^www.//g file_name
```